# Why is Typescript infering an empty object in this simple case

Tags: typescript

Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%2F%20Case%20that%20doesn't%20work%0D%0Atype%20Transformer%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Aconst%20identity%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(a%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20a%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20HardInferenceFn%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T%2C%20transform%3A%20Transformer%3CT%3E%20%7C%20T)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20hardInference%3A%20HardInferenceFn%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20myTransformedValue%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aconst%20myTransformedValue%20%3D%20hardInference('foo'%2C%20identity)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%20Now%20splitted%0D%0Ainterface%20TransformFn%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(transform%3A%20Transformer%3CT%3E%20%7C%20T)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20EasyInferenceFn%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T)%3A%20TransformFn%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20easyInference%3A%20EasyInferenceFn%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20myTransformedValueFixed%20%3D%20string%0D%0Aconst%20myTransformedValueFixed%20%3D%20easyInference('foo')(identity)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%20The%20issue%20is%20by%20adding%20the%20%7C%20T%20to%20transform%20parameter.%20If%20we%20take%20it%20out%2C%20it%20works%20properly%0D%0Ainterface%20FixedInferenceFn%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T%2C%20transform%3A%20Transformer%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20fixedInference%3A%20FixedInferenceFn%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20myTransformedValueFixed2%20%3D%20string%0D%0Aconst%20myTransformedValueFixed2%20%3D%20fixedInference('foo'%2C%20identity)%3B) for live demo.

Given the following code:

```
type Transformer<T> = (t: T) => T;
const identity = <T>(a: T) => a;

interface HardInferenceFn {
    <T>(value: T, transform: Transformer<T> | T): T
}
declare const hardInference: HardInferenceFn;

const myTransformedValue = hardInference('foo', identity);
```

Logically, the type of `myTransformedValue` should be `string`, but it's an empty object instead.

By playing around, I found that what's confusing tsc is the `| T` around the transform parameter, if we take it out, then myTransformedValue will have the expected type.

Why is this happening? Also, is there a way to help tsc by telling him to infer only based on the first parameter, but not on the second one, as it's clearly what's confusing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
export type NoInfer<T> = T & {[K in keyof T]: T[K]};
```

Mapped types defer inference: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-322267089

This should work now:

```
interface HardInferenceFn {
    <T>(value: T, transform: Transformer<NoInfer<T>> | T): T
}
```

Comment: Woah, that's cool, although a bit hacky.... I still wonder why TS gets confused on the original example.... maybe it's worth filling a bug?